# How to catch a broken database connection

Tags: java, try-catch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm working on an app that retrieves from and enters information to a database, using Spring JDBC template.  On the service tier, I would like to set up some logic to catch an exception if the database goes down.  However, I have no idea how to do this.  I'm able to set up the methods to catch if they fail, but I'd like set up specific logic for the server going down.

Comment: How are you connecting to the DB?

Comment: Remotely, using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option - you can create a sceduler which will check database connectivity.

Database connectivity could be checked executing a simple query or via [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) interface:

```
boolean isValid(int timeout) throws SQLException
```

> Returns true if the connection has not been closed and is still valid.
>   The driver shall submit a query on the connection or use some other
>   mechanism that positively verifies the connection is still valid when
>   this method is called. The query submitted by the driver to validate
>   the connection shall be executed in the context of the current
>   transaction.

An example of checking database connectivity via Spring scheduler:

```
@Service
public class ConnectionListener {

    private Connection connection;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         connection = jdbcTemplate.getDatasource().getConnection();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000) // check every 60 sec
    public void checkConnection() {
        try {
            connection.isValid(10);
        } catch (SQLException e) { // Or just handle it here
            throw new ConnectionTimeoutException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You need some additional cnfiguration to handle exceptions thrown from Spring Scheduler:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
class SchedulingConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(...);
    }
}
```

Sceduler also could be implemented with `ExecutorService`.

```
@Service
class ConnectionLisener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    private Connection connection;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        connection = jdbcTemplate.getDatasource().getConnection();
        checkConnection();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    public void checkConnection() {
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                connection.isValid(10);
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                // handle your exception
            }
        }, 60, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

That's a general overview and just a couple of hints for doing further research.

Just one note that if a server is going down you need a disaster recovery, catching an exception will not help. That's a big infrastructure and architectural task, not the responsibility of single application.